# NoResponseException on MultiUserChat room creation

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack, xmppframework, multiuserchat

I am trying to create a MultiUser Chat room using Java..

This is my code...

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("ip_address", 5222, "admin.com");
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);

XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login(username, password);

MultiUserChat mucRoom = new MultiUserChat(connection, groupId@hostname);
mucRoom.create("unio_groups_" + groupId);
```

However, I am getting an excepton "org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException"..

Comment: Do you miss login in server and much more. I suggest you to start from smack tutorial...

Comment: I added code to login to the server. I am getting the same exception "org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException".....    also I am getting following error on the console                                    Sep 12, 2016 1:03:01 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
stream:error (conflict) text: Replaced by new connection

Comment: Do you really miss a lot of things.http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html

Comment: I changed the chat room name to <some_name>@conference.hostname and then it worked..                                                                                 MultiUserChat mucRoom = new MultiUserChat(connection, <some_name>@conference.hostname);                               Thank you.